# In Play Store, how to install live version when you are an internal tester

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-internal-testing

I am new to these... but I could not find any documentation explaining how to choose between installing the live version or the version for internal testers.

In my case, it seems I can only install or update the version for internal testers only.

Comment: what is "live version" and "internal testers"? do you mean beta/alpha channels? you can install only newest app version, if you have published beta with higher `versionCode` then for your "internal testers" will see and install only this version (as above: newest, highest version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you should leave `beta tester program` from Google Play app
- [image: List item]
- then from Google Play app go to `Settings` > `General` > and turn off `internal app sharing`
  [image]
- then uninstall the app and wait for 10 minutes, now you can install production version

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

- Delete the Internal Testing version of the app.
- On the device, Sign in to a different Google Account that is not in the Internal Testing.
- Delete the Google Account from the device enrolled in the Internal Testing.
- Go back to the Play Store, and make sure it's signed into the Google Account that is not in Internal Testing.
- I was now able to download the live version of the app

Answer (score 0):

Enable Internal app sharing from mobile and from Google Play Console.

From Google Play Console under App bundle explorer you can get and share download links for all builds and versions you have.